# Dropped fields in edited data

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have very little experience using Python and have spent the better part of today trying to cobble together a script for ArcGIS Pro using AI powered solutions (its all I got!). My dilemma is this:
I have an original data set in one schema that has 5 fields that were dropped when we clipped up the data into smaller workshares into a different schema. These workshares have been heavily edited. Luckily all 52 of the feature classes inside this schema have an attribute value that was preserved and is the same in both .gdbs. I want to take the original fields and using that preserved attribute value copy in the missing 5 fields. I do have some options I can data load into that original schema and have the fields present and have `Null` values or I can leave it in the current schema without those 5 fields. Does anyone have a solution that would not go feature class by feature class?

```
import arcpy

# Set the paths to the geodatabases
geodatabaseA = r"B:\location of editied data"
geodatabaseB = r"B:\location of original data"

# Set the common attribute field name
commonField = "Unique Entity Identifier"

# Set the fields to update in geodatabase A with corresponding fields from geodatabase B
fieldsToUpdate = {
    "ax_globalid": "ax_globalid",
    "ax_linkid": "ax_linkid",
    "Orig_ZI026_CTUU": "Orig_ZI026_CTUU",
    "Orig_ZI001_SDP": "Orig_ZI001_SDP",
    "Orig_Version": "Orig_Version"
}

# Set the feature class to omit from the attribute copy process
featureClassToOmit = "ResourceSrf"

# Get the list of feature classes in geodatabase A
featureClassesA = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", geodatabaseA)

# Get the list of feature classes in geodatabase B
featureClassesB = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", geodatabaseB)

# Iterate through each feature class in geodatabase A
for featureClassA in featureClassesA:
    # Check if the feature class exists in geodatabase B and is not the feature class to omit
    if featureClassA in featureClassesB and featureClassA != featureClassToOmit:
        # Join fields
        fieldList = list(fieldsToUpdate.values())
        arcpy.JoinField_management(
            geodatabaseA + "\\" + featureClassA,
            commonField,
            geodatabaseB + "\\" + featureClassA,
            commonField,
            fieldList
        )

        # Calculate fields to populate null or blank fields
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(
            geodatabaseA + "\\" + featureClassA,
            list(fieldsToUpdate.keys())
        ) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                for fieldA, fieldB in fieldsToUpdate.items():
                    row[fieldA] = row[fieldB]
                cursor.updateRow(row)

        # Remove join
        arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(geodatabaseA + "\\" + featureClassA, featureClassA)

print("Attribute copy process completed successfully!")
```

This script immediately prints attribute copy process completed successfully! after a nanosecond and nothing has been done to the data.

Comment: Use correct name for common field. What you show is alias. Delete everything after join field line.